# Train timetable over Easter holidays in Sydney

Tags: trains, sydney

Will trains be running to their normal timetable over Easter in Sydney? or will they run a reduced service?  The dates are 25th March - 28th March.

Looking online I can't seem to find any information which leads me to believe they will run normally.

In particular I'm looking for the timetable for the Airport link on Monday morning, as I need to catch an 8:30AM flight.  It normally has trains starting at 5AM from the townhall to the international terminal.

Also I'm looking for information on the Blue Mountain line for Saturday and Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sydney Train generally run to a weekend timetable on holidays.  Easter timetables will likely be slightly different as there will potentially be additional trains specifically for trips to the Easter Show, however the airport line will likely run to a Saturday/Sunday timetable on all days from Friday to Monday (inclusive).